# Eclipse says "You have an error in your sql syntax", but the same query works in workbench. Where is the problem?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this preprared statement that doesn't works in ecplise, but for workbench is ok, what can i do?

```
public void aggiornaArma(Arma Armi) throws SQLException {
PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
try {
    myStmt=myConn.prepareStatement("update arma"
+"set danni=?,Descrizione=?,costo=?,impugnatura=?,tipo=?"
            +" where nome=?");
    myStmt.setInt(1, Armi.getDanni());
    myStmt.setString(2,Armi.getDescrizione());
    myStmt.setInt(3,Armi.getCosto());
    myStmt.setString(4, Armi.getImpugnatura());
    myStmt.setString(5,Armi.getTipo());
    myStmt.setString(6,Armi.getNome());
    myStmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: no space between `arma` and `set` in your query.

Comment: You're assuming that the code you've written produces the same SQL code which you are manually entering into SQL Workbench.  That assumption is false.  Always validate, never assume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

could be is related  to the absence of spaces between table name and set try add

```
 myStmt=myConn.prepareStatement("update arma "
  +" set danni=?,Descrizione=?,costo=?,impugnatura=?,tipo=?"
        +" where nome=?");
```